# wifi connections not showing up for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless

Been trying since yesterday night, with lots of googling.. followed many instructions from different websites that had similar posts, but none of these worked. so decided to post a question myself.

I'm new to Linux, so please excuse me if I sound ignorant.

I don't see any connection listed. could someone please shed some light?

Comment: Run the command `sudo service network-manager restart` in your terminal. It worked for me. Hope it works for you too!

Comment: I tried that..nothing happens..not helping..

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday and i used this command :

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

And the list appear again

Comment: tried that too..

Comment: lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s20u2  Interface doesn't support scanning.